# How to copy values from one attribute column to another with Python/QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, shapefile, pyqgis

I have one shapefile with two columns and I want  to copy the values from column 'A' to column 'B' (in the same shapefile).

I need to do this with a script, because at the end I want to iterate through all shapefiles in one folder. But first, the step described above would help a lot!

It has to be easy as I'm a beginner.

I am using QGIS 2.18.21.

Comment: Which QGIS version are you using? :)

Comment: QGIS 2.8.2. But I think that doesn' matter because I use the Python console. At the end I want to iterate over a lot of shapefiles.

Comment: QGIS 2.8 is _very_ old, is there a reason not to get a more recent version? The Python API would have undergone changes since then. Could you add some more details please such as: are you wanting to copy values from a field in one shapefile to a field in another shapefile (in which case, maybe [this post](copy column into another layer column programatically) might help? Are these shapefiles already loaded into QGIS?

Comment: Hi Joseph. I've updated the QGIS Version and add some informations.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like the following script which let's you choose a folder, iterates through all shapefiles and copies the values from an *"origin field"* to a *"target field"*. You can create a script from `Processing Toolbox > Scripts > Tools > Create new script`:

```
##Example=name
##Folder=folder

# Import required modules
import glob, os
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, edit

# Iterate through all files only ending in .shp (i.e. shapefiles)
for shapefile in glob.glob(Folder + "/*.shp"):
    # Get file name
    name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(shapefile))[0]
    # Read file as a vector layer
    layer = QgsVectorLayer(shapefile, name, 'ogr')
    # Set the origin field
    origin_field = 'oldField'
    # Set the target field
    target_field = 'newField'
    # Get index of target field
    idx = layer.fieldNameIndex(target_field)
    # Start editing the layer
    with edit(layer):
        # Iterate through each feature
        for feat in layer.getFeatures():
            # Copy values from origin field to target field
            layer.changeAttributeValue(feat.id(), idx, feat[origin_field])
```

Comment: Ahhhrgg, I was so close. Thank you very much, it work's :)

Comment: @RobertBK - Most welcome but it's great that you gave it a good go! :)